# Symfony - Disable auto-setting of charset - SET NAMES utf8

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I've added the following line to my `/etc/my.cnf` file:

```
init-connect = 'SET NAMES utf8'
```

Restarted the server and the command works as expected. However, Symfony (1.4) also issues the same exact command for EVERY query via:

```
// lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection/Mysql.php
// line 125
public function setCharset($charset) {
    $query = 'SET NAMES ' . $this->quote($charset);
    $this->exec($query);
    parent::setCharset($charset);
}
```

I'm curious, is there an elegant way to disable this auto-setting of charset? Issuing two queries that do the same thing, for every query from Symfony, doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Copy this event listener from `lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/database/sfDoctrineConnectionListener.class.php` to `lib/database/sfDoctrineConnectionListener.class.php` and remove line #31 `$this->connection->setCharset($this->encoding);` and clear the cache.
It is not so elegant, but you can not just simply un-register the listener.

Comment: Not a good idea to mess with the source code. I wonder if there is a way to disable it via projectConfiguration...

Comment: Im going to check into it in the next few days, I'll let you know if I can find a way to do it without touching the source code.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I think there is no other way to do this because the listener is registered in `sfDoctrineDatabase` line #95 and there isn't any option to avoid this. There is a callback function `configureDoctrineConnection` called just after the listener addition, where you can modify the connection but I can't find any way to unregister a listener that is already registered.

Comment: Ahhh I see... you are probably right, but I would like to confirm myself. Thanks for the tip.